# Python Regex express for 2nd last word

Tags: python, regex

Assuming the following returns a match object = '21',

```
test = re.compile(r'\b\S+\.?$', re.IGNORECASE)

text = 'Random Big Things 21'

test(text)
```

How do I modify the regex to extract out 'Things' in Python?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(\S+)\s+\S+\s*$` https://regex101.com/r/lOhH0i/1/ or perhaps `\S+(?=\s+\S+\s*$)` https://regex101.com/r/7jaLFi/1

Comment: `text.split()[-2]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the second last item of a sentence only by regex you can use

```
text = 'Random Big Things 21'
print(re.findall("\w+", text)[-2])
```

This will extract any character one or more until the next non-character and it will return a list that you can get by -2 the second last match.

Answer (score 0):

What about reversing the string first and then finding the first word after the first space, that would give you the 2nd last word:

```
import re
text = 'Random Big Things 21'
test = re.search('(?<=\s)\w+', text[::-1])
print(test.group(0)[::-1])
```

This returns `Things`.

Note that I use the slicing notation `s[::-1]` to reverse a string `s`.

Also note that once you find the word, you have to reverse it again.